# Redrawing NSTextAttachments in an UITextView with attributed text

Tags: ios, uitextview, nstextattachment

I have a NSTextAttachment subclass with overridden  
 `attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:proposedLineFragment:glyphPosition:characterIndex:`
 `imageForBounds:textContainer:characterIndex:`.

I need to redraw the attachment(s) at some point. Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the UITextView doesn't work.

Any ideas? I'd like to avoid recreating attachments and/or the attributed string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll want to use one of `textView.layoutManager`'s methods.

- `invalidateDisplayCharacterRange:`

  - `imageForBounds:textContainer:characterIndex:` will be called again.
  - `attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:[...]Index:` will **not** be called again.
  - Good if the `image` has been changed with another one of the **same** size.
- `invalidateLayoutForCharacterRange:actualCharacterRange:`

  - `imageForBounds:textContainer:characterIndex:` will be called again.
  - `attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:[...]Index:` will be called again.
  - Good if the `image` has been changed with another one of a **different** size.

If you just want to update a single attachment, you may find this helper method I wrote helpful:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)attachment {
    __block NSRange ret;
    [self.textStorage enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName
                                 inRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.textStorage.length)
                                 options:0
                              usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
                                  if (attachment == value) {
                                      ret = range;
                                      *stop = YES;
                                  }
                              }];
    return ret;
}
```

You can pass the resulting `NSRange` of this method to the first argument of either of those `invalidate` methods. For the `actualCharacterRange:` argument of the second method, I've been passing in `NULL` without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after some digging, that can done by invalidating the layout manager:

```
[textView.layoutManager invalidate....]
```

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/invalidateDisplayForCharacterRange:)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to change the NSTextAttachment which is init by a image, I suggest you to use

```
setAttachmentSize:size forGlyphRange:range
```